# Black-box testing for IOS devices

Tags: ios, testing, black-box-testing

I am looking for some tools that would enable an IOS app to be tested in an automated way without necessarily having access to the code (essentially black box testing).  Currently I am exploring something like  [robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to do just that in Android, but I also need to be able to test IOS apps.  Does anyone have any experience or suggestions for doing this in IOS?

Comment: Frank-Cucumber, UI Automation. Unfortunately, every testing framework has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have build in with Xcode Instruments [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html).
But I recommend [Appium](http://appium.io) because it supports Android and iOS.